# Range notation and current row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I wonder how does work the following and is it documented somewhere?

I have the sheet:

```
A         B
-----------------
1
2
3         =$A:$A
4
5         =$A:$A
```

For column B (row 3 and 5) I see corresponding values from column A. It looks like `=$A:$A` (or even `=$A$2:$A$5` etc) works like `=$A$3` and `=$A$5` in some automagical manner (and no needs to specify different formulas for every cell in B).

I like such behaviour but wish to be sure that it is a reliable solution.

Comment: I was thinking about it but not sure that it answers.

`=$A:$A` neither returns full list of values from $A:$A nor extends values to multiple rows. It looks that Sheets automatically replaces `=$A:$A` with something like `=INDEX($A:$A; ROW())` but it is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

- standalone **`=$A:$A`** means nothing, but if you use it in an array like **`=ARRAYFORMULA(=$A:$A)`** and you have some input in **A** column then it will return you everything you have in **A** column

  [image: 1]

---

- if you want to get cell notation of current row type in **`=ROW()`** and for full notation try:

  - **`=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4)`**
  - **`=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 3)`**
  - **`=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 2)`**
  - **`=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 1)`**

    ---

    [image: 4]

Comment: > standalone =$A:$A means nothing

I was thinking so but see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14aI0YZfIp9xVlkUO2rx69Tmltc7JtkLbiiI0NmKNtSk/edit?usp=sharing.

It looks like =$A:$A works like some kind of array getter "=$A:$A[ROW()]". And I still did not find where such behaviour documented.

Comment: But I do not use ARRAYFORMULA but  `="A:A is " & A:A` expands to 'A:A is 2', 'A:A is 5' etc. And it is not clear how to call such type of reference.

Comment: How it can be "nothing" when in test sheet above it is alone and is anything?

And Sheets somehow knows that **only** single row from A:A matrix should be displayed.